# Error with link text at the bottom of the post

Tags: bug

I have a question about my Database Administrators Stack Exchange post: [Microsoft SQL database table size](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/163296/microsoft-sql-database-table-size)

Hi, just letting you know there is a problem with the linking text at the bottom of posts:

```
Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email, , , or .
```

Platform is Windows 10, web browser is Firefox. I do use AdBlockPlus and a popup script blocker.

---

Update:

I posted a new question on stack exchange.

The link text exhibited the same behaviour. I then disabled AdBlockPlus, refreshed and the link text was correct. AdBlockPlus is in the out of the box configuration and is the latest version.

[image: ABP on vs off]

Top image is with ABP on, bottom image is ABP off.

Comment: What problem is there?

Comment: Does it consistently show like that on all unanswered questions or was it only on yours? Did you try refreshing the page at the time (bypassing the cache, too)?

Comment: Can you show a screen shot? And the relevant portion of view source? Is there space for the words Google+, Twitter, etc.? Maybe you have a plugin or style sheet that is overriding the color (making them white) or hiding them completely.

Comment: Sorry, it's too late now as the question has been answered so it no longer shows the text down the bottom. On other people's questions it shows "Can you help? Database Administrators Stack Exchange depends on everyone sharing their knowledge. If you're able to answer this question, please do!". I will keep a watch for it the next time I post a question.

Comment: This is part of the HTML sent from the server. It does not get added client side so I assume that you must have something that removes or hides these links.

Answer (score 6):

*Works on my machine*

Perhaps specify your OS / Browser / any extensions you use.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: Do you have a link to a post I can go to that will generate the message like that, and I will check. I am not sure how to do that without posting a new question.

Comment: @Darren here's a sample: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42083049/sql-query-returns-resultset-and-messages-or-error-can-sql-query-return-anything i think you just need to find questions with no answers.

Comment: Sorry, as above, I only get the "answer this question" information.

Comment: @Darren are you logged in?

Comment: @Darren try this instead: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/163445/innodb-ignoring-the-redo-log-due-to-missing-mlog-checkpoint

Comment: Still only the "answer this question" text on that latest link. Thanks for your efforts, I'll just check what it does next time I post a question and if it's still a problem will follow up then (and do more testing).